# MS Access Application.Run from WPF Application returns AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, ms-access-2010, .net-4.5

Getting AccessViolationException and MS Access crash since we Update our WPF Soulution from .net Framework 4.0 to 4.5. (or Framework 4.5 is installed local)

We have a own Thread for the WPF Gui. 
When we want to start a Access Form from a WPF Form we are getting an AccessViolationException.
The active Thread when we call "Application.Run" is our own WPF thread.
The Access Thread state is "Background"

short Excample: Start Access -> Call WPF GUI -> Call Access Application = Exception

Is it possible to activate the Access Thread or call the Method "Run" on this Thread?
Or is there another Solution?

Are there some major changes in .net Framework 4.5 for Threading that will throw this Exception?

Thanks, Tim

call access form:

```
using Application = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application;

Application.Run(procedure, ref arg1, ref arg2, ref arg3, ref arg4, ref arg5, ref arg6, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing);
```

And call WPF Form from Access looks like this:

```
Declare Sub ActivityLog_ShowForProductionOrder Lib "MawiLib.dll" (ByVal ProductionOrderID As Long, ByVal UserID As String) 

Call ActivityLog_ShowForProductionOrder(ProductionOrderID, UserID)
```

Comment: Could you show the code that calls WPF gui, and the code that calls back to Access? :)

Comment: added to question...i hope it helps

Comment: FIXED.

We have to get the access application directly before we want to use the Application with Application.Run.

You can get the Application with this following function:

Application = (Application)Marshal.BindToMoniker(_dbPath);

Tim